# Get item in List<T> from index, but loop around the list

Tags: c#, linq

If I had the list

```cs
List<string> fruits = new List<string>(){"apple", "pear", "banana"}
```

how could I change

```cs
int i = 0;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruits[i]);
    i++;
}
```

to output

```
apple
pear
banana
apple
pear
banana
...
```

instead of making an index out of range exception once we reach the end of the list?

In my actual code, I have hundreds of List all of different sizes. I have a Timer which calls a method at regular intervals, and the method needs to return one value from each List, ensuring that eventually all items in each list are returned equally as often.

Because `i` will eventually get very big, the solution below is not optimal.

```cs
int i = 0;
while(true)
{
    int a = i;
    while(a > fruits.Count)
    {
        a -= fruits.Count;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(fruits[a]);
}
```

Here is my actual code which needs to be fixed:

```cs
private static int _purgeNumber;
private static async Task<List<AutopurgeRow>> GetRowsToPurgeAsync()
{
    List<AutopurgeRow> rows = await Database.Data.Autopurge.GetRowsAsync(enabledOnly: true);

    List<AutopurgeRow> rowsToPurge = new List<AutopurgeRow>();
        foreach (SocketGuild guild in _client.Guilds)
        {
            if (rowsToPurge.Count(x => x.GuildId == guild.Id) == 0)
            {
                List<AutopurgeRow> guildRows = rows.Where(x => x.GuildId == guild.Id).OrderBy(x => x.ChannelId).ToList();
                AutopurgeRow row = guildRows[_purgeNumber % guildRows.Count];
                rowsToPurge.Add(row);
            }
        _purgeNumber++;
        if (_purgeNumber == int.MaxValue) _purgeNumber = 0;
    }

    return rowsToPurge;
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto As stated in my question, it needs to work on several lists with one value of i.

Comment: `i = (i + 1) % fruits.Count`

Comment: "*The solution needs to work with several lists of different sizes*" -- it's not clear what you mean. Can you [edit] your question to include example code which demonstrates your actual problem, rather than using simpler example code and a vague statement saying how your actual problem is more complex?

Comment: why dont you use for loop?

Comment: @canton7 My apologies, I've made the edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Still not clear enough, provide a sample code of your case

Comment: @230Daniel So if you have multiple lists, don't make all examples use *one* list, because all we can assume is that you have different lists that are passed to one method

Comment: Okay, in your actual code you’re already using `%` instead of a while loop. Is there still a specific bug? (You should probably switch to describing the overall problem and asking for the best way to solve it regardless.)

Comment: @Ry- Yeah. I managed to convince myself that the % method doesn't work for some reason. The code I was having issues with is a more complex version of the above but it should function in a very similar way. I just tested the basic code above and it worked perfectly, I suppose that I must have some other odd bug which I can find. Thank you though for the answer, it'll be useful for others coming across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> int a = i;
> while (a > fruits.Count)
> {
>     a -= fruits.Count;
> }
> ```

A more efficient way to do this (and more correct, since `>` should be `>=`) is to take the remainder when `i` is divided by `fruits.Count` with the `%` operator:

```
int a = i % fruits.Count;
```